# How to use logging for print statements inside a python package?

Tags: python, django, logging

I am working on a Django project which uses some packages that print statements out to the console (some of these packages are by made me). These print statements represent important info and cannot be removed just by commenting out the prints.

Can someone guide me as to how to redirect such print statements to a logger?

Also what would be the best practice for printing stuff to console while developing a package?

Comment: "best practice for printing stuff to console" - use the logging module.

Comment: By using the logging module, users of your package can choose how to handle the logging events themselves. They may not have a console. They may want to output to a console and to a file. They may want to send E-mails. By using print(...) you make these harder for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module and replace your print statements with logging statements instead.

You could also do the following to redirect your print statements to a file but this is not best practice.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple, but less recommended solution. Copy the stdout in the terminal and append to a log file. If you are using bash or zsh:

test.py just prints 'hello world':

```
python3 test.py > >(tee -a log.txt)
```

The standard output will be printed to the screen, but also appended (tee -a parameter) to log.txt